# parse timestamp with millisecond in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime, time

Assuming I have a bunch of timestamps like "11/05/2010 16:27:26.003", how do parse them with millisecond in Perl.

Essentially, I would like to compare the timestamp to see if they are before or after a specific time.

I tried using Time::Local, but it seems that Time::Local is only capable to parse up second. And Time::HiRes, on the other hand, isn't really made for parsing text.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Time::Local` and just add the `.003` to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local;

my $timestring = "11/05/2010 16:27:26.003";
my ($mon, $d, $y, $h, $min, $s, $fraction) =
    $timestring =~ m{(..)/(..)/(....) (..):(..):(..)([.]...)};
$y -= 1900;
$mon--;

my $seconds = timelocal($s, $min, $h, $d, $mon, $y) + $fraction;

print "seconds: $seconds\n";
print "milliseconds: ", $seconds * 1_000, "\n";
```

Comment: sorry for the seemingly trivial question. I am very new to perl.I am wondering what is the purpose of the "$timestring =~ m{....." line?

Comment: @Derek That is a regex.  The `.` matches any character and the parentheses (i.e. `()`) capture that part of the string, so the regex matches against the string `$timestring` capturing the bits we care about (e.g. hour, minute, second, etc.) and discarding the parts we don't (for instance, the `"/"` characters).  You can read more about regexes in [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 17):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $Strp = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(
    pattern => '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N',
    time_zone   => '-0800',
);

my $now = DateTime->now;
my $dt  = $Strp->parse_datetime('11/05/2010 23:16:42.003');
my $delta = $now - $dt;

print DateTime->compare( $now, $dt );
print $delta->millisecond;
```

Comment: And for reference: http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm#STRPTIME_PATTERN_TOKENS