# Convert string date to Perl DateTime

Tags: perl, datetime

I'm a newbie in Perl, so please be patient with me:

I am writing a log parser and have successfully parsed "Dec 1 17:45:36.**185**" into it's individual units (month, day, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds).  I want to convert this to Perl's `DateTime` object.

I'm having trouble with the milliseconds portion: **.185**.

I hope to use `DateTime::Format::Strptime` like such:

```
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime(
    pattern    => "%b %d %H:%M:%S"    # how do I add the milliseconds part?
)
```

Comment: See [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127102/parse-timestamp-with-millisecond-in-perl/4127356#4127356) to "parse timestamp with millisecond in Perl".

Comment: He doesn't need to parse it, he has already parsed the string. He is looking for a way to output the info he has parsed into a string format.  I would help figure this out for you as I have done a lot of work in Perl in the past, but I am on my iPad right now. If you don't have an answer tomorrow I will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display milliseconds, use this format `%3N`:

```
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime(
    pattern    => "%b %d %H:%M:%S.%3N"    # now we have the milliseconds part
)
```

The number jut before the `N` means the number of digits that will be displayed.
The number displayed is truncated, not rounded.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missunderstanding you. But if you want to have an object of this: http://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime and know the individual numbers, why not use the constructor like so:

```
  use DateTime;

$dt = DateTime->new(
  year       => 1964,
  month      => 10,
  day        => 16,
  hour       => 16,
  minute     => 12,
  second     => 47,
  nanosecond => 500000000,
  time_zone  => 'Asia/Taipei',
);
```

Or do you wonder how to format that information into a string later? In that case, you could just use `sprintf` and DateTimes get methods to produce any format you want.

edit: I think i understood you now. DataTime does not have ms, only ns. When constructing, that is no problem, as you can just put `nanosecond => ($ms*1000000)` but i see how that can be a problem when using `::Strptime`.
I cannot install DateTime here to test it, but the CPAN does say

```
%N

Nanoseconds. For other sub-second values use %[number]N.
```

So when you have a DateTime object with nanoseconds, you could play with that `[number]` value to see what it does and when you have found a way to tell it that you like ms, it should even work for parsing.

Comment: Thank you, for being thorough but I'm sorry I have to award @M42 the correct answer because it is short and to the point and solves my problem (you did too).  But I did upvote your answer.